# RDLC files prompted to update, then causes report definition error

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I am working with an older web application which uses RDLC files to display SQL queries on webpages as well as to convert to excel spreadsheets. there are some formatting errors id like to tweak but im unable to use the report designer and would really like to avoid manually editing the RDLC.

I have report viewer installed with my 2015 enterprise edition of visual studios and when i try and open the RDLC file it prompts me with

> Do you want to convert this report to the latest RDLC format? Please click OK to proceed or Cancel to open in the XML editor

When i convert i am no longer able to compile due to an error in the report definition.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.       D:\NCS Workspace\CBSRepo\CBS1\CBS1\EquipmentReport.rdlc 1

I believe this is because im using a new version of report viewer that comes with VS 2015 and the RDLC file is set at a 2005 edition of report viewer.

RDLC file's Report Definition before converting:

`<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">`

My Web.config assembly references

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
```

**Question:** how can i use report designer for my project? id like to avoid updating each RDLC just so i can edit the design layout. is it possible in VS 2015 to use an older version of Report Viewer compatible with the RDLC files i have?

i have tried installing older versions of report viewer redistributables but im very new to everything C# related atm and could really use some guidance.

[Report Viewer 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=21916)

please, please, please let me know if i can provide anything else to help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SSDT November 2015 Preview for Visual Studio 2015 installed? If not, BI aspects (such as SSRS, SSAS, SSIS) are not available to Visual Studio 2015.

[See link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)

> The unified template collection is only available in SSDT Peview for Visual Studio 2015. To create Analysis Services data models, Reporting Services reports, or Integration Services packages in Visual Studio 2013 or to add non-preview versions of the BI templates to Visual Studio 2015, you will need to install the SSDT-BI version for Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: okay i have installed SSDT November 2015 Preview what does this allow me to do in reference to my problem?

Comment: okay ive tried all my previous attempts again with SSDT Preview but i still cannot either:
A. open any rdlc file w/o needing to convert to a newer format (which breaks the name space, tried updating web config references but to no avail)
B. help convert my current VS to handle current RDLC files

what am i doing wrong? i see many post on this issue with little to no solutions that work for me.